# using vba i fetched 5000 records from db, how to loop to paste evrey 1000 records into a new worksheet?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am not sure how to loop to fetch only 1000 records and paste values in a new sheet so that as a result the workbook has 5 sheets. 
Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks!

```
Sub text_analysis()
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sConnString As String
Dim rsstring As String
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim NewWorkbook As Workbook
Set NewWorkbook = Workbooks.Add

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;" & _
              "Initial Catalog=MDM-FINAL;" & _
              "Integrated Security=SSPI;"

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

conn.Open sConnString
rsstring = "exec text_analysis;"
rs.Open rsstring, sConnString

NewWorkbook.Activate
Do Until rs.EOF
Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs, MaxRows:=100000
ActiveSheet.Name = "Text Analysis"
Range("A1").Value = "SAP Code 1"
Range("B1").Value = "SAP Desc 1"
Range("C1").Value = "SAP Code 2"
Range("D1").Value = "SAP Desc 2"
Range("E1").Value = "Diff Count"
Range("F1").Value = "Diff Value"
Range("G1").Value = "Similar %"
Range("H1").Value = "Similar Partial %"
Range("I1").Value = "Similar Sort %"
Range("J1").Value = "Similar Set %"
Loop

rs.Close
conn.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the fields collection, since you're looping over the recordset anyway.

```
Do Until rs.EOF
Range("A1").Value = rs.Fields("SAP Code 1")
...
Loop
```

You could use 2 indexer variables in the loop: One to go to the next sheet and one to keep track of the row loop.

```
Dim i as integer
Dim j as integer
Dim ws as worksheet

j = 1
i = 1
Set ws = Worksheets(j)
Do Until rs.EOF
    i = i + 1
    If i % 1000 = 0 then
        i = 1
        j = j + 1
        set ws = Worksheets(j)
    End if
    ws.range("A" & i).value = rs.Fields("SAP Code 1")
    ....
Loop
```

Comment: Not at all. It's just a way to make this "spread it over 5 sheets in 1000 rows" work. Agree that it is far from optimized, however it's the answer to the specific question.

Answer (score 0):

`CopyFromRecordset` does not have the ability to do what you want to do.

You may want to look in to breaking your SQL into pieces using OFFSET-FETCH as shown here: http://www.dofactory.com/sql/order-by-offset-fetch

Answer (score 0):

this method is getting data as Variant from recordset

```
Sub text_analysis()
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sConnString As String
Dim rsstring As String
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim NewWorkbook As Workbook
Set NewWorkbook = Workbooks.Add

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;" & _
              "Initial Catalog=MDM-FINAL;" & _
              "Integrated Security=SSPI;"

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

conn.Open sConnString
rsstring = "exec text_analysis;"
rs.Open rsstring, sConnString

'get data as Variant from recordset
    Dim R As Long, m As Long, c As Integer
    Dim i As Long, j As Integer
    Dim vR, Ws As Worksheet
    vR = rs.getRows
    R = UBound(vR, 2)
    c = UBound(vR, 1)
    For m = 0 To R Step 1000
        ReDim vResult(1 To 1000, 1 To c + 1)
        For i = 0 To 999
            If i + m > R Then Exit For
            For j = 0 To c
                vResult(i + 1, j + 1) = vR(j, i + m)
            Next j
        Next i
        Set Ws = Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
        With Ws
            For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
               .Cells(1, i + 1).Value = rs.Fields(i).Name
            Next
            Range("a2").Resize(1000, c + 1) = vResult
        End With
    Next m


rs.Close
conn.Close

End Sub
```